# Problem using turtlebot + kinect

Tags: navigation, kinect, octomap, turtlebot, octovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good Morning!
I'm facing some troubles to create an octomap using RGBDSLAM with kinect in a turtlebot, without GUI.
Every time when i stop to capturing frames and send the data to octomap_server, something unusual happen, the octomap only contains the last frame captured.
I've already tried to create the octomap with kinect only, and it worked! But running turtlebot + kinect i can't create a full octomap from the area.

My steps were:
Running turtlebot `roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch`

And the controls `roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch`

Running Openni `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`

And the rgbdslam / octomap_server  `roslaunch rgbdslam headless.launch`  `roslaunch rgbdslam octomap_server.launch`

After the capture ends i send data to octomap_server, and then run octomap_saver

PS.: I don't think the problem is related to the capture process, because the memory raises when the process starts and stabilize when it stops

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200394/problem-using-turtlebot-+-kinect/) by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2015-01-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
You can debug the problem by something like `rostopic echo /rgbdslam/batch_clouds/header`, which will show you which/how many clouds rgbdslam sends out.

What hardware are you using? The communication between rgbdslam and octomap server is known to be brittle on slow machines and when the data needs to be transfered between machines.

Which version of RGBDSLAM are you using? The hydro version [on github](http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2) lets you save the octomap without the octomap_server by using the octomap library directly.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) on 2015-01-12**:
I'm using RGBDSLAM v2 on hydro version, i guess the problem was related to the "send_cloud_rate" parameter somehow, i just decreased the rate and it worked!
I'll debug to confirm if that was the problem, Thanks!

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2015-01-14**:
The send_cloud_rate just throttles the sending to x clouds per second. Probably the octomap server or the network couldn't keep up. If octomap server is using 100% of a single CPU core, consider to lower the resolution of the octomap.

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-26**:
Hi, I started working on rgbd slam with TurtleBot, ros hydro Ubunto 12.04 I followed this link:http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/ to install rgbd slam, and after I had a GUI window as the window exactly in this link,

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-26**:
with the two posts below:
waiting for visual picture on topic waiting for depth image is topic there is no picture,

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-26**:
i think it was a problem with topics in launch files can some one help me and send to me the launch of openni+rgbdslam.launch openni.launch rgbdslam.launch